# how to switch between two threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, executorservice

let's assume that i have two threads namely "t1 and t2". in the run method of t1 there will be two tasks to be executed, the first task is to display some data, while the second
one is to execute a time consuming operation let's assume it will take 10 minutes. in the run method of t2, two tasks to be executed as well, the first task is to display some
data while the second one is to do a less time consumeing operation that lasts for 5 minutes.

**pseudo code**

```
thread t1 {

    run() {
        -display info
        -time consuming operation for 10 minutes
    }
}

thread t2 {

    run() {
        -display info
        -time consuming operation for 5 minutes
    }
}
```

what i want to do is, when the time consuming operation of t1 starts, i want to put t2 on pause for 2 minutes, and after the 2 minutes elapses t2 should continue working.
and when the time consuming task of t2 starts, t1 should be paused for 2 minutes as well and it continues to work after the 2 minutes elapses.

I want to do that in Android. please let me know the state-of-the-art as for that matter, and what is the recommended approaches to do it.

Comment: Are operations "pausable" = consisting of repeatedly running smaller chunks of work where you could check a condition while looping? Pausing threads themselves is really really not something you want to do.

Comment: @Fildor what i meant by "pausing" athread is, to put it to sleep or make it inactive

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html Scroll down to "Why are Thread.suspend and Thread.resume deprecated?"

Comment: You have many possibilities. From using Conditions to setting sleeptimes ... but it depends on your time-consuming work. If it is one atomic blocking call, there is not much you can do.

Comment: Your requirement is pretty vague.  E.g., You say you want T2 to pause for two minutes when T1 starts its work.  Why?  Does it matter how much progress T2 has already made with its own work?  Do you have any expectations of what T2 will be doing at the moment when it is "paused"?  What is it that you want to prevent T2 from doing during those two minutes?  (i.e., what bad thing would happen if it did _not_ pause?)  Do these threads loop? or are they one-time-only?  If they loop, what do they _wait_ for?  If one-time-only, what starts them, and why?